How to trigger doGet() on an apps script web app using python (with service account)?
I want to trigger the doGet(e) event from the apps script web app, which returns JSON.
Our web apps cannot be accessed outside our org domain, thus service account is needed.
I executed the code below, but "An error occurred: 401 Client Error."
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
import requests

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = r'C:\Users\USER\Documents\fga-openrpa-sa.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/path/exec?page=something'

try:
    response = authed_session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response content:", response.text)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)


I also tried Oauth but service account is much easier to setup. I also don't have a working code for that.

I think that in your situation, the modification depends on the settings of your Web Apps. But, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot know the values of Execute as: and Who has access to the app:. So, in this case, I would like to propose 2 patterns.
First, please confirm that your Google Apps Script project has already been shared with the email of the service account.
Pattern 1:
In this pattern, it supposes that the values of Execute as: and Who has access to the app: are "Me" and "Anyone with Google account" or "Anyone within the domain can access it", respectively.
In this case, please modify your script as follows.
From:
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request']

To:
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

In the current stage, in order to request Web Apps, it seems that the scopes of Drive API like https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly are required to be included.
The whole modified script is as follows.
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
import requests


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = r'C:\Users\USER\Documents\fga-openrpa-sa.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/path/exec?page=something'

try:
    response = authed_session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response content:", response.text)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

When I tested this modified script, I confirmed that the script worked.
Pattern 2:
In this pattern, it supposes that the values of Execute as: and Who has access to the app: are "User accessing the web app" and "Anyone with Google account" or "Anyone within the domain can access it", respectively.
In this case, it seems that when Execute as: is "User accessing the web app", the service account cannot be used. So, please change Execute as: from "User accessing the web app" to "Me", and modify the modification of "Pattern 1", and test it again.
Reference:

Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)


Deployment settings on web app:
Execute as: Me

File/web app is already shared to the service account.
Execute as: Me
Access: Anyone within the domain
It returned a 200 but I'm not really sure if this leads to the web app. I also check that doGet() was not triggered when running this code.

@Lemuel Dingal Thank you for replying. About File/web app is already shared to the service account. Execute as: Me Access: Anyone within the domain It returned a 200 but I'm not really sure if this leads to the web app. I also check that doGet() was not triggered when running this code., when I tested my script, no error occurred. I don't know your script. So, in your situation, your Google Apps Script works? How about using a simple script? By the way, in your situation, your service account has permission to request Web Apps from the administrator. Is my understanding correct?

I think that's the problem. I haven't assigned the script as GCP project. I might redo every thing and deploy as API executable.

Service account to oAuth
